# Lua: Regex and Lua Patterns

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

```
local code = [[
client_script 'Bait.lua'

client_script 'Test.lua' --Test
]]
```

how am I gonna make a regex/pattern that takes everything that's between `client_script '` and `' --Test`

Comment: `code:match"client_script%s*'([^\n]+)'%s*%-%-Test"`

Comment: next time it would be nice if you'd share some own ideas first. this is not a coding service or online Lua pattern generator. a solution to this problem can easily be achieved with the Lua reference manual within minutes even if you know nothing about patterns befor

Answer (score 1):

`code` seems to be Lua code and thus any pattern-based solution will fail if an equivalent but different piece of code is used instead (`"` instead of `'`, parentheses, line breaks, multi-line comments etc.). Why not parse it as Lua?

```
local code = [[
client_script 'Bait.lua'

client_script 'Test.lua' --Test
]]

local scripts = {}
local newenv = {
  client_script = function(name)
    table.insert(scripts, name)
  end
}

load("local _ENV=...;"..code)(newenv)

for i, v in ipairs(scripts) do
  print(v)
end
```

This parses and loads the code, but uses `newenv` as the environment with a different definition of `client_script` that stores the value. Note that FiveM also uses `client_scripts` and a couple of other functions that will have to be present (but most of them can be simply specified as `function()end`).

Also the code above works only for Lua 5.2 and higher. The difference for Lua 5.1 is the line with `load`, which has to be changed to this:

```
setfenv(loadstring(code), newenv)()
```

The reason is that `load` and `loadstring` got merged in 5.2, and accessing the environment is only defined in terms of accessing the `_ENV` variable, so there is no specific environment attached to a function anymore.